# fastest way to implement which

Tags: r, performance, dataframe

I am  sure that there is an elegant and fast way to populate a data frame column besides using a which() statement in a for-loop...

```
colors = (
    "#D53E4F" "#FC8D59" "#FEE08B" 
    "#FFFFBF" "#E6F598" "#99D594" "#3288BD" 
)
n = 6277
wxData = data.frame(
    x = numeric(n - 1), 
    y = numeric(n - 1), 
    z = numeric(n - 1), 
    c = character(n - 1), 
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE 
)
for (j in 1 : n-1) {
    wxData$x[j]     = xCoord[[1]][j]  #"data.frame"
    wxData$y[j]     = yCoord[[1]][j]  #"data.frame"
    wxData$z[j]     = dbz[[1]][j]     #"data.frame"
    colorIndx      = which(wxData$z[j] == colorRanges) 
    wxData$c[j] = colors[colorIndx]  
}
```

Apologies if it's been asked before, but I did look.

Comment: Could you describe in words what your code does? It's a much more elegant and fast way to communicate than uncommented code... And maybe give definitions for the objects you don't define, `xCoord`, `yCoord`, `dbz`, `colorRanges` ?

Comment: I'm also confused about why you set `n = 6277` but then only ever seem to use `n - 1`... why not `n = 6276`? I think, though, the answer to your question is `match`.

Comment: `for (j in 1 : n-1)` is doing `for (j in (1:n) - 1)`, not `for (j in 1:(n-1))`. Is that your intention?

Comment: Ok.  Mea culpa.  I have x, y coordinates (proj ~= xCoord, yCoord in UTM/WGS-84/km units) and an index z which is an integer pointer into the colorRange E(30,  35, ..., 65).  On matching z[j] to entry in colorRange, return color string from colors.  N just happens to be the length of vectors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, given the provided code is not executable, the loop over

```
which( values[j] == array )
```

can be substituted with one line without loop

```
match(values, array)
```

For example:

```
values = c('a','a','b','c','b','a')
array = c('a','b','c')
match(values, array)

# 1 1 2 3 2 1
```

Comment: Thanks very much.

Comment: You are welcome. I am a big fan of the `match` function.